# RSS Feed For O365 Roadmap

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Is there an RSS feed available for the O365 roadmap page?

https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-roadmap

Comment: Here is another link I got from Tim's link: [http://feeds.feedburner.com/Office365RoadmapWatcher?format=xml](http://feeds.feedburner.com/Office365RoadmapWatcher?format=xml)

Answer (score 0):

its not available and also several other people has requested microsoft in the forums but they never implemented this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out the Office 365 Roadmap Watch: http://www.roadmapwatch.com/home/subscribe

Answer (score 0):

No, it's currently available in MS Teams site but not in Community Sites in SPO.  There are SPFX solution examples for API driven samples/rss available, in addition to possibity use embed iframe option (server owner will need to allow embed iframe).